# Export-SPweb specific number of list items

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell

Is it possible to use Export-SPweb to export a specific number of list items, and not the entire list? For example, the list has 100,000 items and I would like to export just 1-25,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible with `Export-SPWeb`. `Export-SPWeb` can be limited with the depth of versions of items, but not the number of items within a List.